# Find records in same table with different company id but some other same values

Tags: postgresql

I have subscriptions table that looks roughly:

table subscriptions
id (auto generated id)
company_id
city
state
subscription_date

I would like to find records that:

A) are of **different company** (company id) but have **same city/state**

B) are of **different company** (company id) but have **same subscription date**

For address, I was doing:

```
select distinct on (t1.company_id) t1.company_id, t2.company_id, t1.city, t1.state
from subscription t1, subscription t2
where t1.company_id <> t2.company_id
and t1.city = t2.city
and t1.state = t2.state
order by t1.company_id
```

Is this efficient and accurate way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you consider "duplicates" but here's what I came up with.

```
SELECT t1.company_id, t2.company_id, t1.city, t1.state, t2.subscription_date,
CASE WHEN t1.subscription_date = t2.subscription_date
then 'DateMatch' ELSE 'City/State Match' END AS MatchType
    FROM subscriptions t1
JOIN subscriptions t2
    ON (t1.city = t2.city
    AND t1.state = t2.state)
    OR (
      t1.subscription_date = t2.subscription_date
      )
WHERE t1.company_id <> t2.company_id
order by MatchType, t1.company_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bb04d/10

Answer (score 1):

I create a table like yours 
there is My data :

```
mysql> select * from tab;
+------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
| id   | company | city    | state | date        |
+------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | 1       | kenitra | good  | 06/07/13    |
|    2 | 2       | kenitra | good  | 08/08/13    |
|    3 | 3       | rabat   | good  | 06/07/13    |
+------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
```

and I try this code

```
mysql> select t1.company_id company from tab t1, tab t2 where t1.city = t2.city and t2.state = t2.state and t1.company_id <> t2.company_id;
```

the result is:

```
+---------+
| company |
+---------+
| 2       |
| 1       |
+---------+
```

and for this :

```
 mysql> select t1.company_id company from tab t1, tab t2 where t1.date = t2.date and t1.comp
        any_id <> t2.company_id;
```

the result is :

```
+---------+
| company |
+---------+
| 3       |
| 1       |
+---------+
```

I hope this will be helpful for you